# CSS3 pseudo class not first and last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have some following HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>number 1</li>
    <li>number 2</li>
    <li>number 3</li>
    <li>number 4</li>
    <li>number 5</li>
    <li>number 6</li>
    <li>number 7</li>
    <li>number 8</li>
    <li>number 9</li>
    <li>number 10</li>
</ul>
```

How can I use CSS3 pseudo-classes to make any `li` element which is not the first or last have a `background-color` of `tomato` for example? It seems that I could use the `:not` selector.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Two ways :

you can set a generic rule, and then override it for `:first-child` and `:last-child` items. This plays to CSS strengths:

```
 li { background: red; }
 li:first-child, li:last-child { background: white; }
```

Or, you can use the `:not` keyword combined combining the two:

```
li { background: white; }
li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) { background: red; }
```

Of the two, I personally prefer the first - it's easier to comprehend and maintain (in my opinion).

Comment: Note that this doesn't work on IE8, as `:last-child` it's not supported.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a pen
http://codepen.io/vendruscolo/pen/AeHtG

You have to combine two `:not()` pseudo classes:

```
li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  background: red;
}
```

Here's the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot): as stated there, it's not supported on IE < 9, while it's well supported on other browsers.

If you need IE 8 support, you have to rely on Javascript or use another class to indicate which element is the last child. In fact, IE 8 (and lower) doesn't support the `:last-child` pseudo class.

Comment: Yes.It's very useful when it's not supported on IE < 9.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
.candidate_verified_items ul li:not(:last-child),
.candidate_verified_items ul li:first-child:not(:last-child) {
   border-right: 1px dashed #7b8db9;
}
```